# Numerical Linear Algebra Typo

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

In a subsection titled "Defective Eigenvalues and Matrices" the opening paragraph reads

> Although a generic matrix has algebraic and geometric multiplicities
>   that are equal (namely, all 1), this is by no means true of every
>   matrix.

Maybe it's just me not being used to the jargon, but I take *generic* to mean *any matrix, in general*; but then the author's statement is obviously false. I think this must be an incorrect intpretation (by me). So what's going here? Is *generic* a specialized term?

I've seen no definition of *generic* in the text so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a specialized use of generic in mathematics.  Informally, a property is generic if it holds for most cases, or except on a set of measure 0, or something similar to that.  [See the Wikipedia discussion of this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_property)